# Show message and Reload page in C# asp.net webform

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to show message and reload page at same time,

But it has been kept reload page and can not stop.

How can I fix this problem? thanks.

```
   protected void btnCk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string a= Request.Form["a"];
        string b= Request.Form["b"];
        string c= Request.Form["c"];

        string strReturn = null;

        strReturn = U9.Data.LoginData.LoginChange(a, b, c);

        if (strReturn == "0")
        {
            Response.Write("<Script language='JavaScript'>alert('OK');</Script>");   
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("<Script language='JavaScript'>alert('"+ strReturn.ToString() + "');</Script>");
        }

        Response.Write("<Script language='JavaScript'>window.location.reload();</Script>");
        Response.End();
    }
```

Comment: it endless reload page, just like loop.

Comment: *it endless reload page* How?

Comment: It's unclear to me, what you trying to do.

Comment: can not end reload page

Comment: reload will have repeat the Button Click problem

Comment: use `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('OK');window.location='default.aspx';", true);`  for if and else separately. and change your page at the place of default.aspx

Comment: @Div thanks,it OK now.

Comment: Glad to know that! I added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this issue is because of you are you're trying with `Response.Write` which writes a string to an HTTP response output stream.

In this case, you can use [`ClientScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9h4dk8y(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
if (strReturn == "0")
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('OK');window.location='default.aspx';", true);
}
else
{
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('"+ strReturn.ToString() + "');window.location='default.aspx';", true);
}
```

And change your page at the place of `default.aspx`

Hope this helps!